# Random characters from memory when reading from file using fscanf

Tags: c, memory, random, character, scanf

```
        //create the array from file
        char *array[100];
        char string[80];
        FILE * file;
        file = fopen( "file.txt" , "r");
        if (file) {
            int k = 0;
            while (fscanf(file, "%s", string)!=EOF){
                array[k] = strdup(string);
                k++;
            }                            
            fclose(file);
        }

        //print the history array for debugging
        for(int k = 0; k<sizeof(array); k++){
            printf("the element at %d is: %s\n", k, array[k]);
        }
```

The resulting array has random characters from memory which are not present in the file. Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: Your code happily overflows both of your arrays

Comment: yes i know. But each line of the file will have a max length of 80, and the file will have a max length of 100 lines.

Comment: First things first. Is the `array` supposed to have lines from the file, or words from the file?

Comment: If the lines have a maximum length of 80 characters, your buffer needs to fit 81 characters.

Comment: array is supposed to have lines from a text file.

Comment: Second, `k < sizeof(array)` is the same as `k < 400`, which is not what you want.

Comment: @user3133300 "each line of the file will have a max length of 80 [...]" **never** trust your input. buffer overflows are security holes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems in the code.

The first is that you are using `fscanf` to read the file, instead of `fgets`. `fscanf` with a format of `"%s"` will read one word from the file. `fgets` reads a line.

The second problem is the last `for` loop which uses `sizeof(array)`. On a 32-bit machine, `sizeof(array)` is 100*4 = 400. What you want is to count the number of lines that have been read from the file, and then use that count in the `for` loop.

With that in mind, here's how I would write the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    char *array[100];
    char string[80];
    FILE *fp;

    if ( (fp = fopen( "file.txt" , "r")) == NULL )
    {
        printf( "File not found\n" );
        exit( 1 );
    }

    int count = 0;
    while ( fgets( string, sizeof(string), fp ) != NULL )
    {
        string[strcspn(string,"\n")] = '\0';
        if ( count < 100 )
        {
            array[count] = strdup( string );
            count++;
        }
    }

    fclose( fp );

    for ( int k = 0; k < count; k++ )
        printf( "the element at %d is: %s\n", k, array[k] );
}
```

The line

```
string[strcspn(string,"\n")] = '\0';
```

removes the newline, if any, from the string. This is necessary since `fgets` will retain the newline.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want to read lines of text, use:

   ```
   fgets(line, sizeof(line), file);
   ```
2. If a line can contain `80` characters, you need to define `line` to be an array of at least `81` characters -- to allow an extra space for the terminating null character.

   ```
   char line[81];
   ```
3. You need to store the number of lines read so that when writing the lines out, you don't try to write any more than you read. Make sure you don't read any more than the number of lines `array` is capable of holding.

   ```
   int numLinesRead = 0;
   if (file) {
       int k = 0;
       while (fscanf(file, "%s", string)!=EOF && k < 100 ){
           array[k] = strdup(string);
           k++;     
       }                            
       fclose(file);
       numLinesRead = k;
   }
   ```
4. Don't write any more than the number of lines read.

   ```
   for(int k = 0; k<numberOfLinesRead; k++){
       printf("the element at %d is: %s\n", k, array[k]);
   }
   ```

Comment: Suspect when OP commented [But each line of the file will have a max length of 80](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32747949/random-characters-from-memory-when-reading-from-file-using-fscanf#comment53336700_32747949), that does not include the ending `'\n'`.  Recommend `char line[80 + 1 + 1];`

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in this code ...

```
    char *array[100];
    char string[80];
```

so far, so good, now let's look at this:

```
        int k = 0;
        while (fscanf(file, "%s", string)!=EOF){
            array[k] = strdup(string);
            k++;
        }
```

Issues here:

1. you don't check `k`. This should stop if `k` reached `100`
2. checking for `EOF` is wrong. Other things could fail, too.
3. `%s` will only read up to the next whitespace, probably not what you want.
4. `%s` will read as long as there are non-whitespace characters, so it *will* overflow your `string`, given malicious input.

A correct version would e.g. look like this:

```
        int k = 0;
        while (k < 100 && fgets(string, 80, file)){
            array[k] = strdup(string);
            k++;
        }
```

Then to the next problematic part:

```
    for(int k = 0; k<sizeof(array); k++){
        printf("the element at %d is: %s\n", k, array[k]);
    }
```

`sizeof()` gives you the **size in bytes** of its argument. The size of an array is **fixed**, it doesn't matter how many elements you actually stored. The elements are pointers, so taking more than 1 byte.

Correct version:

```
    int lines = 0; // nothing read
    if (file) {
        int k = 0;
        while (k < 100 && fgets(string, 80, file)){
            array[k] = strdup(string);
            k++;
        }                            
        fclose(file);
        lines = k;
    }

    for(int k = 0; k<lines; k++){
        printf("the element at %d is: %s\n", k, array[k]);
    }
```